# Basic probability question about delivery watches

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The question is stated as:

A shipment of watches is shipped in two boxes. One contains 150 watches of which
21 are broken. The second box contains 100 of which 4 are broken. A box is chosen
at random and then from the chosen box a watch is picked at random. It turns out to
be broken. What is the probability is was shipped in the first box?

My attempt:

Define the following events,

$S_1 := \text{The watch is shipped in the first box.}$

$ B_1 :=\text{The first box is choosen}$

$A := \text{The choosen watch is broken}$

The probability we want to calculate is then given by bayes theorem,

$P(S_1|A)=\frac{P(A|S_1)P(S_1)}{P(A)}$

My question: is $P(A) = \frac{25}{250}$ or do you need to use the law of total probability

$P(A) = P(A|B_1)P(B_1) + P(A|B_1^c)P(B_1^c)$ ? Or is the approach wrong in general?

Comment: The probability of choosing a broken watch, in general, is indeed calculated by the last equation that you wrote. I would write it like so:
$$
P(A) = P(A|B_1) P(B_1) + P(A|B_2)P(B_2)
$$
which evaluates to $\frac{9}{100}$. So $25/250$ is wrong because you need to take into consideration that the probability distribution for which box is selected, is 50/50 and not according to how many watches there are.

Comment: @MattiP. Thank you Matti :)

Comment: @MattiP. The answer is still not right if I use the $\frac{9}{100}$ the possible answers are: a. 1/2 b. 3/5 c. 4/25 d. 7/9 e.2/3. Maybe you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just go ahead and post a full solution. I'll change the notation a bit to my own taste. Let

- $A=$watch is broken
- $B_1=$ box 1 is chosen
- $B_2=$ box 2 is chosen

The following probabilities are given:

- $P(A|B_1) = \frac{21}{150}$
- $P(A|B_2) = \frac{4}{100}$
- $P(B_1) = P(B_2) = \frac{1}{2}$

The probability we want to calculate is
$P(B_1|A)$ and indeed we can use Bayes' theorem for this:
$$
P(B_1 | A) = \frac{P(A|B_1)P(B_1)}{P(A)}
$$
The denominator is always the tricky part in these calculations. We can use the law of total probability:
$$
P(A) = P(A|B_1)P(B_1) + P(A|B_2)P(B_2)
     = \frac{21}{150} \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{100}\frac{1}{2}
     = \frac{9}{100}
$$
Now we know all the values required, and we can just plug in the values to the final expression:

> $$ P(B_1 | A) = \frac{\frac{21}{150} \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{9}{100}} = \frac{7}{9} $$

Comment: Thanks! One question why is the event $B_1|A$ equivalent to the event the watch was shipped in box 1 given that the choosen watch is broken. I probably see things the wrong way, thanks again.

Comment: What aspect of that is confusing to you? Since the watches stay in the boxes that they were shipped in, leads to the logic
$$
\text{you pick a watch from Box 1} \Rightarrow \text{that watch was shipped in Box 1}
$$